# How to get rid right side shadow but maintain bottom shadow on button

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, shadow

I have the loop creating a row of button and I have the following code to set the shadow. How do I get rid of the right side shadow but maintain the bottom shadow?

```
    button.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 7.0f;
    button.layer.shadowRadius = 1.0f;
    button.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    button.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0f, 2.0f);
    button.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5f;
    button.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
```

[image: Pic]

Comment: Why don't you add every buttons on an `UIView` and give this view bottom shadow instead of giving shadow for each button?

Comment: I think you should not apply bottom shadow to each button rather then take UIView and put all buttons row inside it and apply bottom shadow to that View only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Answer

As suggested added UIView

```
navigationView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(X_BUFFER+5,Y_POS_BTN,self.view.frame.size.width-10,HEIGHT_BTN)];
navigationView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

[self.view addSubview:navigationView];

UIBezierPath *shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:self.navigationView.bounds];
self.navigationView.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
self.navigationView.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
self.navigationView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(5.0f, 5.0f);
self.navigationView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.8f;
self.navigationView.layer.shadowPath = shadowPath.CGPath;
```